# Joomla 2.5 language code in URL. How to disable?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I have Joomla 2.5 with built-it multilanguage system. Main language is russian and second is english.
In 2 specific articles I have iframes with src="/freeflight2/form.php". In russian version of the site the iframe loading correctly. But in english I get URL of iframe with language code: http://xxx/en/freefligh2/en/form.php which causing 404.

I also tried to write full url, but Joomla again inserting language code.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Is this custom or within Joomla?  If custom have you tried using JPATH to get the base path?  If within Joomla are you using an editor like JCE to create the iframes?